# How to access json object using node.js express.js

Tags: javascript, json

my json is like this

```
var jsonObj = JSON.stringify(arr, null, 4);
console.log(jsonObj);
```

my output like this

[image: json output]

I want access each and every element in this json. Plese provide me a solution to do this task

Comment: Giving an example of what you've attempted so far may give others an idea for what you're trying to do?? You're able to access any of these values via your `arr` object.

Comment: Why are you stringifying the array? Just loop over it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell it looks like you have an array of objects and within that object is a sub array ("subActs"). To be able to iterate over all the objects in the "subActs" array you need to iterate over it this way:

```
jsonObject.forEach(function(object) {
   object.subActs.forEach(function(subObject) {
     console.log(subObject);
  });
});
```

This will iterate through the entire object and just print to the console the subActs array objects.

Comment: JSONObject is a string, so you can't really forEach over it.